# How to order the same set of records two times, the second ordering performing independently from the first one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to create a sort of deductive query, where the same records are ordered multiple times and the order each time is performed independently from previous orders.

Such as:

```
tallest_trees = Trees.order(:height => :desc).limit(10) # Gets 10 of the tallest trees out of all available trees
tallest_trees.order(:width => :desc) # From the 10 of the tallest trees, gets the widest trees **without** any regard to their height
```

I've attempted to do it in a similar way as above, but the result has always been that it attempts to order the, in this case, trees, *both* by height and width at the same time, which is the opposite of my needs.

There hasn't been any difference in regards to using either ActiveRecord or SQL directly. I believe the answer is that I somehow have to "stabilize" the previous query so that the second one doesn't just continue it, but instead order it anew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways. First:

```
base_scope = Trees.limit(10)
tallest_trees = base_scope.order(height: :desc)
widest_trees = base_scope.order(width: :desc)
```

Second - with [reorder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-reorder) method:

```
tallest_trees = Trees.order(height: :desc).limit(10)
widest_trees = tallest_trees.reorder(width: :desc)
```

Comment: `reorder` that's it! Thanks!